# Changing quote xcode 6

Tags: ios, string, swift, xcode6

hey i want to know how to add a feature like which random string will appear after every new day. I have done this with the button.when a person is click on button a new quote appear.But i want that a person recieve a new quote every new day.
can anyone write a code about this like only example

Comment: You need to be more specific with your question.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Q: How exactly should the quote be presented to the user?  As a pop-up when he logs on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you could set a local notifications that will fire each 24 hour then display any quote.
So a day contains 86400 seconds, we could use a timer that will count down from 86400 seconds to zero, when it hits zero we reset the timer and remind them a quote

```
    @IBOutlet weak var label:UILabel!
    var countdown = 86400
    var timer : NSTimer!


     func Notification(){
      timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
var notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: Double(countdown*10))
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    notification.alertTitle = "Quote is now available"
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}

  func update(){
    countdown--;
    if countdown == 0 {
     timer.invalidate()
     var quote = "God is Great"
     self.label.text = quote
    }
```

> To show random images when button is clicked :

```
 var counter = 0

@IBOutlet weak var imageView:UIImageView!

@IBAction func ButtonWasTapped(sender:UIButton){

    switch(counter){

    case 0: imageView.image = UIImage(named: "nameOFtheImage.jpg")
    break

    case 1: imageView.image = UIImage(named: "nameOFtheImage.jpg")
        break
    case 2: imageView.image = UIImage(named: "nameOFtheImage.jpg")
        break
    case 3: imageView.image = UIImage(named: "nameOFtheImage.jpg")
        break
    case 4: imageView.image = UIImage(named: "nameOFtheImage.jpg")
        break
    default:
         counter = 0
        break;

    }
 counter++
}
```

Comment: can you tell me some hint by writing some code @lamar

Comment: check the code update @shivam

Comment: wow thanks man it helped me a alot @lamar

Comment: and you can tell me one more thing like how to change background image after clicking on button like i want that when person clicks on button the both quote and background image should change so if you know anything about this you can also thanks alot for your help

Comment: Again you have two option do you want to change the controller background or you want to use a uiimageview

Comment: i want to use a uiimageview @lamar

Comment: create an **IBOutlet for the UIImageView** then inside of the button function just  **imageview.image = UIImage(named:"\(name of the image)")**. that should do the trick and please vote the answer lol

Comment: haha thanks but some code will be good thanks alot sorry to disturb you @lamar

Comment: its ok lol keep learning@shivam

Comment: lol then tell me the some code for changing the background like i have 3-4 pics and i already have made the iboutlet and its working withe the single image

Comment: how to create an array fro random images @Lamar

Comment: yeah i just edited the code @shivam

Comment: thanks alot man but cant we make an array of images and then use arcrandom ? @Lamar

Comment: check the code and try to change to swift @Lamar

Comment: I said try using array and if you are stuck just post your code